# What I should use GTK+ or QT

Tags: c++, linux, qt, gtk

It's maybe silly question. But I'm new in Linux developing. And I don't know what I should use for creating GUI. 
As I understood that there's no qt in every Linux. For example I checked Debian 6 and I didn't find qt there. But there's in Ubuntu...
I'm not gonna develop complex interface just few windows. So what I should use?
What about GTK+? Does every build of Linux support this one? 
Or Is't impossible to create one build for all builds of Linux? I noticed that skype suggests to download few version depends on Linux version.
I don't want to bring dynamic qt libraries with my program. It's big...

Comment: Debian (& Ubuntu & Mint) has Qt and GTK. The license (LGPL) of Qt and of GTK strongly suggests dynamic linking -because you legally need to permit your user to improve or upgrade Qt or GTK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are linux machines without neither GTK or QT, just check the API and see which one you like the most, or which one is better for your project.

Distributions use packages, which list the needed libraries; so when you install something, the package manager will also know which libraries are needed and install them as well.

Distributions have different package managers, for example debian and ubuntu use apt-get/dpkg, while red hat/fedora use rpm. The different skype packages are just due to the different package managing systems found in the various distributions.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's what I wanted to know.